# WPF C# Open a new Window from a Page

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

maybe my question is a little bit stupid, but i can not found a solution.
My Problem is:
I have loaded a page into an WPF Window and now i wanna open a new Window out of the Page by an event in this page.

Has somebody a solution?

```
MyWindow mwindow = new MyWindow();
mwindow.show();
```

does not work in a page!

Thanks a lot

Comment: `mwindow.Show();` but check if the event was really fired e.g. set a breakpoint.

Comment: the problem is: mwindow.show() get an compilere error... the event fired

Comment: `Show()` begins with upper-cased letter. There's a typo.

Comment: thanks for help - error in front of keyboard ;-)